# Why are my props not being passed into my component when mount rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am writing unit-tests using Enzyme and Jest for my React App frontend. When I try to render the login screen it fails to see some of the props I'm passing when trying to mount() render. Shallow rendering works fine and I'm able to test my componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps methods.

I've attempted multiple ways of rendering. Using mount() with a Provider, hardcode passing the props in. Nothing seems to be working.

Below is a working test and a broken test. The first works fine however the mount test is broken:

I'm passing these props through:

```
let props = {
    actions: mockProps.actions,
    auth: {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isFetching: false
    },
    history: mockProps.history,
    location: {
        pathname: "/login",
        search: "",
        hash: "",
        key: "0m32x8"
    },
    match: mockProps.match
}
```

mockProps is a json file with example props from the React Dev Tool in chrome.

```
// Working Shallow Rendered Test
it('componentWillReceiveProps', () => {
    const componentWillReceivePropsSpy = jest.spyOn(Login.prototype, 'componentWillReceiveProps')
    shallowWrapper.setProps({ location: { search: "testing" } })
    expect(componentWillReceivePropsSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
})

// Broken Mount Rendered Test
it('Mount Test', () => {
    mount(<Provider store={store}><Login {...props}/></Provider>)
})
```

**The error occurs when the component tries to set the initial state here**:

```
state = {
    shouldRedirect: false,
    errorShown: false,
    fields: {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    },
    token: q.parse(this.props.location.search).token,
    fieldErrors: {}
};
```

It fails to find `this.props.location.search`.

Answer (score 3):

While using High Order Components It's better to export the base component as well(before wrapping it), this way we can test without the wrapper, and simply pass mocks for the required providers.

I had the same problem and this was how I resolved!

Comment: Could you provide an example with code?